# Automatically inject dependency

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, silex

I can't understand why Silex\Application object is injected in some classes but in others not. Here is an example

Example 1

```
/
 Controllers
   Admin
     LoginController.php


namespace SD\Controllers\Admin;

use Silex\Application;

class LoginController
{
  public function loginAction(\Silex\Application $app)
  {
     //in this method Application object is injected automatically
  }
}
```

Example 2

```
/
 Lib
  RoutesFactory.php

namespace SD\Lib;

use Silex\Application;

class RoutesFactory
{
  public static function make(\Silex\Application $app)
  {
    // in this method Application object is not injected automatically and I get an error saying the object passed to method make is none instead of \Silex\Apllication
  }
}
```

So why the Application object in the first example is injected automatically but in the second not?

Comment: maybe `Silex\Application` can't be injected to static method?

Comment: Already tried with a non static method - it's same

Comment: can you add example of how are you creating these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silex [does parameter conversion](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#route-variables-converters) in controllers (and in controllers only), so in the controllers methods you can type hint and expect to "automatically" have the instance, but not anywhere else. From the [official docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#controllers-in-classes):

> You can (**in the controller method**) use Request and Silex\Application type hints to get $request and $app injected.

NOTE: Emphasis mine, its extracted from the context so I though better to make it clear.

For more details, check the [Silex controller resolver code](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/ControllerResolver.php) and also the [Symfony's HttpKernel one](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php).